# bigint not insert correctly

Tags: mysql, laravel, bigint

I have a database and a bigint column type. Everytime I insert value to this column I always got the wrong number. for example, I insert value "198705122006041001" and it always insert this value "2147483647".

I use laravel for my project, if I use eloquent to display the bigint it wont display correctly but if I use PDO manually, it will display correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has no bigint data type, it overwflows and uses int.max instead. You have to represent bigints as string or float. Be aware, that float is not precise and can lead to surprises.

Do the mathematical transformations in MySQL and don't forget to cast to bigint when necessary.

Comment: My problem is if I use Eloquent to show the values of this column it will reutrn 2147483647 no matter what the value is. If I use PDO manually to retrieve the data, it will show the right value. So how I can handle this Bigint in Eloquent? Converting to varchar/text or string is not an option. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should check this again, because it's definitely `int`, but not `bigint`. `2147483647` is a [maximum possible value for signed `int`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: My problem is if I use Eloquent to show the values of this column it will reutrn 2147483647 no matter what the value is. If I use PDO manually to retrieve the data, it will show the right value.
So how I can handle this Bigint in Eloquent?

Converting to varchar/text or string is not an option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/fbid-bigint-with-model-and-eloquent. A Laravel user had the same problem, and eventually had to cast the result to a string.

Another user comment pointed out that XAMPP provides only a 32-bit PHP binary, which limits the size of a PHP integer.

Check your PHP integer size with this code:

```
<?php

echo "Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE="
  . (PHP_INT_SIZE * 8) 
  . " bits, maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX="
  . PHP_INT_MAX;
```

See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Install https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead and get a 64-bit PHP binary.